# Implicit finite differences: Sufficient conditions for non-negativity

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences

Given the finite difference approximation for black scholes with zero interest rate,

$$
\frac{V_n^{m+1}-V_n^m}{\Delta t} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2 \frac{V_{n+1}^{m}-2V_n^m+V_{n-1}^{m}}{\Delta S^2}=0\\
$$

We can write it as,

$$
\begin{align}
V_n^{m+1} &= -\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 n^2 \Delta t V_{n-1}^m + \left( 1+\sigma^2 n^2 \Delta t \right)V_n^m -\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 n^2 \Delta t V_{n+1}^m\\
&=a_nV_{n-1}^m + b_nV_{n}^m+c_nV_{n+1}^m
\end{align}
$$

Given that $V_n^{m+1} \ge 0 $ for all $n$, what are sufficient conditions for $a_n$, $b_n$, $c_n$ which ensures $V_n^{m} \ge 0 $ for all $n$?

Can someone kindly point me to any available materials on this?

Comment: The proposed method is explicit, or you're trying to solve it back in time?

Comment: @uranix he is going back in time

Comment: it seems $a_n, b_n, c_n \ge 0$ should do it, but it's too restrictive for you.

Comment: Ya trying to solve it back in time. So we know the values of V at m+1 and we are trying to get Vm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that $a_n + b_n + c_n = 1,\; a_n, c_n < 0$. Suppose that $V_n^m$ is negative and is a local minimum.
$$
V_n^m < 0\\
V_{n+1}^m \geq V_n^m\\
V_{n-1}^m \geq V_n^m.
$$
Then
$$
V_n^{m+1} = a_n V_{n-1}^m + b_n V_n^m + c_n V_{n+1}^{m} = 
-a_n (-V_{n-1}^m) + b_n V_n^m - c_n (-V_{n+1}^m) \leq
-a_n (-V_n^m) + b_n V_n^m - c_n (-V_n^m) = V_n^m.
$$
Since $V_n^{m+1} > 0$ then $V_n^m \geq V_n^{m+1} > 0$. So $V_n^m$ can't be negative, contradiction.

Comment: So in the above we've shown that V_n^m cannot be negative, but then what should the sufficient conditions on a,b,c? For example, in a similar analysis for the explicit method, we know that a,b,c must be all positive

Comment: Is the condition simply that a, b, c sum to 1? Which happens to already be the case

Comment: And a and c should be negative. The a, b and c should sum to anything positive. This should be sufficient.